# TypeError when using cxfreeze in ubuntu 12.04 32 bit

Tags: python, c, ubuntu

I am attempting to make a .exe file using cx_freeze on 32-bit Ubuntu 12.04, but am encountering an unexplained TypeError like **"TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable"** . Here is the setup script:

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe


setup(console=['file.py'])
```

Could someone lend a helping hand? Any help will be appreciate.

Comment: this is the whole code error

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. In my python program, I was interacting with some supplementary files (text file for logging) which were present in the same folder where my python script was located. 
I found out that the exe version of my program was trying to find those files and it could not find them, and so returns an error.
Therefore, I copied those file to the same folder where my exe program was located. And, ... yes, **it solved the problem**.